# Would a question exporting from SQL Server 2008 -> SQL Server 2000 go on serverfault or stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Basically my question is in the title.

I desire to ask a question to get some help on moving data from one database to another, but I am not certain where the question should go.

Thank  you.

Comment: My problem is that I have tried various approaches to get this to work, but sql scripts won't work and the export wizard didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your sql scripts aren't working that leads you into the realm of other programming solutions which should go on SO.  SQL Server export/migration questions on SF are typically answered as "Script out the database objects and export your data via SSMS", or "Use a third part product like Red Gate's SQL Data Compare".

Comment: Thank you, guess I will ask my question now. :)

Answer (score 3):

Depends if you're looking for more of a scripting answer or a wizard answer (no, I'm not knocking the wizards).

A scripting approach would go on SO, but a wizard approach (how to properly setup a database migration process through SQL Server Management Studio) best fits in SF.

Answer that, and you'll know where to post. Plus you can also [search all three sites](http://sofum.dillieodigital.net) to see if the question has already been answered for you.

Answer (score 1):

Initially strikes me as a SO question, I suspect you'll be dealing with sql scripts, which are programming related.

Comment: This is a fine line between administration and development, IMO, which is why I thought I would ask.